ping multiple ips in parallel using fping
I have the below simple ping monitor script
#!/bin/bash
while true; do
    HOST=8.8.8.8
    HOST2=8.8.4.4
    
    if [[ "$(fping -I -r 1 $HOST | awk '{print $3}' )" = "alive" ]]; then
        
        sleep 1
        echo "Internet is UP" 
        
    else
        
        if [[ "$(fping -r 1 $HOST2 | awk '{print $3}' )" != "alive" ]]; then
            
            sleep 1
            echo "Internet is Down" 
        fi
    fi
done

What i'd like to do is to be able to ping in parallel and incorporate into my above script i.e.
fping -a -A -c 1 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4 1.1.1.1

And at least one works then "internet is up" but if all fail "internet is down"

Start by storing the ip/host addresses in an array:
hosts=( 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4 1.1.1.1 91.91.91.91)

Feeding the array to the fping call:
$ fping -r1 "${hosts[@]}"
8.8.8.8 is alive
8.8.4.4 is alive
1.1.1.1 is alive
91.91.91.91 is unreachable

fping + grep to determine current status:
status=Down
fping -r1 "${hosts[@]}" | grep -q alive && status=UP
echo "Internet is ${status}"

Taking for a test drive:
With hosts=( 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4 1.1.1.1 91.91.91.91 ) this generates:
Internet is UP

With hosts=( 91.91.91.91 ) this generates:
Internet is Down

If we negate the conditional we can loop while the internet is down (no need for the status variable in this case):
while ! fping -r1 "${hosts[@]}" | grep -q alive
do
    echo "Internet is Down"
    sleep 1
done

echo "Internet is UP"

NOTES:

OP will need to decide how they wish to handle any stderr messages generated by the fping call
while OP has mentioned the desire to run the fping calls in parallel they also said they wish to run fping -a -A -c 1 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4 1.1.1.1 (I take this to imply the need to handle a variable number of ip/host addresses) ...
I have no idea how fping handles multiple addresses - does it run them in parallel or serially? - so if OP is looking for even more parallel capability then it may be necessary to bring xargs or parallel into the mix


Try this:
while true; do
    if fping -r1 $HOST $HOST2 | grep -q alive; then
        sleep 1
        echo "Internet is UP" 
    else
        sleep 1
        echo "Internet is Down" 
    fi
done

Alternatively you can set
hosts=( 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4 )

... with any number of ip addresses and use ...
if fping -r1 "${hosts[@]}" | grep -q alive; then

